# Failed to receive binary data with Android

Tags: android, binary, serial-port

What I want to do is sending 42 bytes binary data from mbed LPC1768 to my Android smartphone. The code I use is as follows.

```
usbIoManager = new SerialInputOutputManager(port,musbListener);
final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.submit(usbIoManager);
```

As you can see, a serial port listener is set.
"musbListener" implements SerialInputOutputManager.Listener.
The callback function (a musbListener's method) is as shown below.

```
@Override
public void onNewData(final byte[] DataBuff) {
    Log.d("DataBuff",DataBuff.toString());
    final float[] Data = decode(DataBuff);
    ...
}
```

Let's see Logcat.

```
D/SerialInputOutputManager: Read data len=14
```

I expect for Android to receive full 42 bytes data, but only 14 bytes are received.

Please tell me what I should do to solve this problem.

Comment: By the way, I'm using a library "usb-serial-for-android".

Comment: Please tell the hex value of those 42 bytes. After that tell the hex value of the 16 bytes received.

Comment: onNewData can be triggered several times.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
I tested this method with 15 bytes in different code, then I found that onNewData was triggered twice, 14bytes and 1 byte, as you stated.
The main cause of the error is the received data array, DataBuff, is located in for sentence whose iteration number is 42. So ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException was thrown, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android/wiki/FAQ#I_observed_codereadcode_data_loss_with_continuous_transfer_at_high_baud_rates) is the best clue to deal with this problem.
Finally I used a for sentence until all data is detected.